# Starting and ending points of a line is given, how to get all the intermediate coordinates ? , android

Tags: android, line, coordinate

**Starting  and ending points of a line is given, how to get all the intermediate coordinates in android ?**

Answer (score 0):

Google for Bresenham's line algorithm!

Answer (score 0):

Equation of a line, two-point form: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Two-point_form

Answer (score 0):

You have two points. All you need is the slope. There is a two-point form for obtaining the slope.